# OnPush change detection strategy has no effect on HostBinding()

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to optimize a complex angular component where data updates very frequently. For this, I am using OnPush change detection strategy which works well and reduces the number of calls to property getters quite significantly. But the HostBindings are still checked the same number of times as was with Default strategy.

Am I missing something or does OnPush have no impact on HostBindings?

Here is a slackblitz example. Do check the console logs.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9w6nwd?file=src/main.ts

Below is a snippet from the example:

```
  @HostBinding('[attr.style]')
  get styles(): string {
    console.log(`cd count: ${++this.cdCount}`);  // stills gets called same no. of times as earlier
    return `--dynamic-height: ${this.calculatedHeight}`;
  }

  cdCount = 0;
  showLinkCount = 0;
  calculatedHeight = 0;

  private _showLink = true;
  set showLink(val: boolean) {
    this._showLink = val;
  }
  get showLink(): boolean {
    console.log(`link count: ${++this.showLinkCount}`); //checked only when I call this.cd.detectChantges()
    return this._showLink;
  }
```

Comment: I think (but don't take my word for it) that it might be managed by the parent cdr. So if you had a parent component, and that parent had OnPush, it would be affected by that strategy.

Comment: @TotallyNewb I don't think so because in my slackblitz example, I have used app component to demonstrate this and there is no parent component for app.

Comment: Well, this means that host is basically bound to the root of the CD tree. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmwd49) example (sorry that it's messy, was in a bit of a hurry) and try changing change detection strategy on parent to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to update the example. It looks like @HostBinding is affected by parent's CD strategy not the host's.

Comment: And because in my example, host is at the root, it is not affected by OnPush strategy. Is this what you meant @TotallyNewb?

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses ZoneJS internally, which monkey patches native JS functions such as `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame`, etc.

Which means, everytime one of those native functions finish, a signal is emitted to Angular to let it know it should check for changes.

If you want to avoid that, use Observables instead, which can be controlled with operators such as `filter`, `distinctUntilChanged`, etc.

Comment: Close, but does not quite answer the question, if HostBinding is effected by the OnPush strategy.

Comment: Indeed, I must have been drunk when I answered this, because this doesn't answer at all the question ...